# Customise SafariViewController with APPAUTH swift

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller, appauth

I am learning ios development with swift and i am implementing Authentication using the appauth pod. My question would be : Is it possible to customise the safariviewcontroller used to login? Are there some samples with swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SFSafariViewController` is not customisable as Apple states -

> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet, use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes, interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the WKWebView class.

Source - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

You may also try `ASWebAuthenticationSession` or `SFAuthenticationSession`.

Comment: Clear! Thanks I want to implement authentication but reading arround on the net a lot of people says it s not a good idea to use resource owner grant type but then actually the UI for login page is rendered in the safariviewcontroller and this is bad for user experience... difficult choice...